# Why aren't my class variables being set?

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, cookies

I am using CodeIgniter to develop my login system.  Through a core extension of the controller class that gets the current user's information, I use $this->user throughout the app controllers to display the user's information.  On my local WAMP server, this works perfectly.  On my web server, however, it always displays the information of the guest after you login.  Note the var_dump towards the bottom of the member get info method.  This always displays the correct account information.  But once I call it from the controller extension, it displays guest information.

The Controller extension class:

```
class MY_Controller extends CI_Controller {

    var $user = array();

    function __construct(){

        parent::__construct();
        $this->benchmark->mark('foo');
        //$this->output->cache(5);
        if(!$this->config->item('global_maintenance')){                 

            $this->member->get_info($this->session->userdata('member_id'));
            if($this->member->error == NULL){

                $this->user = $this->member->info;

            } else {

                die($this->member->error);

            }                   


           } else {

                die('BaseCMD is currently down for routine maintenance.  Please try again later!');

            }

    }

}
```

The member model:

```
<?php

class Member extends CI_Model {

    var $info = array();
    var $activation_code = '';
    var $error = NULL;

    function __construct(){

        parent::__construct();
        $this->error = NULL;

    }

    function default_info(){

        $info = array(
                'id' => 0,
                'display_name' => 'Guest',
                'email_address' => '',
                'password' => '',
                'status' => 0,
                'activation_code' => '',
                'location' => '',
                'date_joined' => '',
                'gender' => '',
                'results_per_page' => 10,
                'admin_emails' => FALSE,
                'member_emails' => FALSE,
                'team' => array('id' => 0),
                'perms' => array(),
                'group' => array('id' => 0),
                'stats' => array(),
                'signature' => '',
                'last_active' => 0,
                'last_forum_visit' => 0,
                'member_profile' => 'Guest',
                'date_of_birth' => '',
                'gender' => '',
                'profile_banner' => '',
                'avatar' => array('url' => '')
            );

        return $info;

    }

    public function get_info($criteria = 0){

        if(is_numeric($criteria)){
            $where = "WHERE m.member_id = ".$criteria;
        } else {
            $where = "WHERE email_address = '".$criteria."'";
        }           

        $query_member = "
            SELECT
                m.member_id AS member_id, m.display_name, m.email_address, m.group_id, m.status, m.activation_code, UNIX_TIMESTAMP(m.date_joined) AS date_joined,
                m.gender, m.location, m.biography, m.mantra, m.birth_date, m.results_per_page, m.admin_emails, m.member_emails, m.last_active, m.avatar_id, 
                m.banner_id, m.signature, m.newsletter_subscription, m.recruiting_status, m.facebook_username, m.website, m.steam_username, m.xboxlive_gamertag, m.psn_id,
                g.group_id, g.title, g.description,
                a.attachment_id, a.file_name,      
                f.message_id, f.author_id, COUNT(f.message_id) AS forum_count,  
                b.attachment_id AS banner_id, b.file_name AS banner_file,
                mr.request_id, mr.author_id, mr.recipient_id, mr.status, COUNT(mr.request_id) AS total_friends,
                tm.team_member_id, tm.member_id, tm.team_id
            FROM members AS m
            LEFT JOIN member_groups AS g ON (m.group_id = g.group_id)   
            LEFT JOIN attachments AS a ON (m.avatar_id = a.attachment_id)         
            LEFT JOIN forum_messages AS f ON (m.member_id = f.author_id)
            LEFT JOIN attachments AS b ON (m.banner_id = b.attachment_id)
            LEFT JOIN member_requests AS mr ON (m.member_id = mr.author_id OR m.member_id = mr.recipient_id) AND mr.status = 1
            LEFT JOIN team_members AS tm ON (m.member_id = tm.member_id) AND date_left = ''
            ".$where."
            GROUP BY m.member_id
            LIMIT 1";     

        //show_error($query_member);     

        if($query_member = $this->db->query($query_member)){

            if($query_member->num_rows() > 0){

                $member = $query_member->row_array();

                $member_id = $member['member_id'];                
                    var_dump($this->session->all_userdata());
                 $info = array(
                    'id' => $member['member_id'],
                    'display_name' => $member['display_name'],
                    'email_address' => $member['email_address'],
                    'status' => ($member['status'] == 0) ? FALSE : TRUE,
                    'activation_code' => $member['activation_code'],
                    'location' => $member['location'],
                    'date_joined' => date('M jS, Y', $member['date_joined']),
                    'gender' => ($member['gender'] == 0) ? 'Male' : 'Female',
                    'results_per_page' => $member['results_per_page'],
                    'admin_emails' => ($member['admin_emails'] == 0) ? FALSE : TRUE,
                    'member_emails' => ($member['member_emails'] == 0) ? FALSE : TRUE,
                    'group' => array(
                        'id' => $member['group_id'],
                        'title' => $member['title'],
                        'description' => $member['description']
                        ),
                    'signature' => $member['signature'],
                    'last_active' => strtotime($member['last_active']),
                    'member_profile' => anchor('members/'.url_title($member['display_name']).'/'.$member['member_id'], $member['display_name']),
                    'newsletter' => ($member['newsletter_subscription'] == 1) ? TRUE : FALSE,
                    'date_of_birth' => date('M jS, Y', strtotime($member['birth_date'])),
                    'birth_date' => date('Y-m-d', strtotime($member['birth_date'])),
                    'age' => floor((time() - strtotime($member['birth_date'])) / (60 * 60 * 24 * 365)),
                    'gender' => $member['gender'],
                    'biography' => $member['biography'],
                    'mantra' => $member['mantra'],
                    'contact' => array(
                        'email' => ($member['member_emails'] == '1') ? $member['email_address'] : NULL,
                        'website' => ($member['website'] != '') ? $member['website'] : NULL,
                        'facebook' => ($member['facebook_username'] != '') ? 'http://www.facebook.com/'.$member['facebook_username'] : NULL,
                        'steam' => ($member['steam_username'] != '') ? 'http://www.steamcommunity.com/id/'.$member['steam_username'] : NULL,                        
                        ),
                    'gaming' => array(
                        'xboxlive' => $member['xboxlive_gamertag'],
                        'psn' => $member['psn_id'],
                        'steam' => $member['steam_username']
                        ),
                    'statistics' => array('post_count' => $member['forum_count']),
                    'avatar' => array(
                        'attachment_id' => $member['attachment_id'],
                        'url' => base_url('attachments/'.$member['file_name'])
                        ),
                    'banner' => array(
                        'id' => $member['banner_id'],
                        'url' => base_url('attachments/'.$member['banner_file'])
                        ),
                    'friend_status' => FALSE,
                    'recruiting_status' => ($member['team_id'] == '' && $member['recruiting_status'] == '1') ? TRUE : FALSE
                    );
                //$info['friend_results'] = $this->friend_results($member_id);
                var_dump($info);
                $this->info = $info;

            } else {

                $this->info = $this->default_info();

            }

        } else {

            $this->error = $this->db->_error_message();
        }
        //show_error(var_dump($this->info));

    }
```

Comment: It looks like the problem is that your database query is returning no results, probably due to session issues. Have you confirmed that the session vars aren't getting lost?

Comment: Just as an example, if you're using a different database for dev vs. production, you might have forgotten to create a ci_sessions database table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, so after dumping the variables from my controller extension, the member model, and my template, I realized that my problems didn't have anything to do with my sessions or my classes.  It was actually my conditional statement that determined if the user was logged in or not that I use in my templates.

```
<?php

if($this->user['id'] === 0){// This is correct.

  echo "You're logged out.";

}

if($this->user['id'] == 0) // This is what I was using and is not correct, apparently.
```

Comment: suggestion: if possible i would suggest checking for login status in your controller, and then calling the appropriate views.